# Decomposability and analytification of coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, gaga

Let $X$ be an affine (algebraic) complex variety and $f:Y \to X$ be a finite morphism. Given any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, we denote by $\mathcal{F}^{an}$ the analytification of $\mathcal{F}$. My question is: if $\mathcal{F}$ is an indecomposable coherent sheaf on $X$, does it necessarily imply that $\mathcal{F}^{an}$ is also indecomposable (as an analytic coherent sheaf)? I am mainly interested in the case when $\mathcal{F}:=f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$. In this case, if we write $\mathcal{F}:=\oplus_i F_i$ with $F_i$ indecomposable, then is $F_i^{an}$ also indecomposable as an analytic coherent sheaf?